# What does vendor mean in web file structure?

Tags: php, html, web-applications

Every now and then I see **vendor** being used in a directory structure on web apps.

Like this:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

What does this mean? Why do people use it?

More importantly, should *I* use it? I make web apps using php and javascript.

Comment: It is used to denote third party plugins...

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It's a common convention to put files coming from various third party sources (the "vendors") in a folder named that way.

You can use it as it makes it clearer what's "from the project" and what is a dependency you rely upon, but it is merely a convention, not an obligation.

Comment: I know @Steve was right first, but I'm marking this as the answer as it's concise.

Answer (score 35):

`/vendor` usually refers to a directory that contains third party plugins.

Answer (score 6):

Most if the time, there are 3rd party libs stored and commonly it's ignored in VCS.